# Javascript onResize trigger screws animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, responsive-design

I'm having a problem with my dropdown after in the midst of calling onResize. On a fresh page load the drop-down nav acts correctly but if you resize the browser and click the drop-down for the sub nav, it moves fast and doesn't stay open.

**Here's a [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemiketm09/wybk4/1/).**

Here's just the JS:

```
var res;
onResize = function() {
var responsive_viewport = $(window).width();
var mobile_menu = $('nav div span');
var mobile_list = $('nav div #main-nav');

if (res){ clearTimeout(res)};
res = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("resize triggered");

    if (responsive_viewport <= 1024) {

        mobile_menu.add(mobile_list).click(function(event) {
            mobile_list.slideToggle('fast', 'swing', function() {
                mobile_list.toggleClass('active');
            });
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        $(document).click(function() {
            if (mobile_list.hasClass('active')) {
                mobile_list.slideToggle('fast', 'swing', function() {
                    mobile_list.removeClass('active');
                });
            }
        });
    }
    if (responsive_viewport <= 768) {
        console.log('on mobile');
        nextvid.addClass('mobile');
    } else {
        nextvid.removeClass('mobile');
    }

},200);
}
$(document).ready(onResize);
$(window).bind('resize', onResize);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is *every* time you resize the window (and I guess counting pageload) you bind to the event of clicking on the item. So when you resize the window once, the event fires twice and the dropdown opens then closes. If you resize the window again, the drop down now opens, closes, then opens again. So long story short you should bind only once! If you then want to change the binding (like if they switch to mobile view) you should then [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) then rebind a different way.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @matty-d. I've tried a few techniques including the simplest, adding `unbind()` before the bing on `$(window)`. Is there an example you could give me based on the jsfiddle?